# Error when running a sample program using vc++ and chai-3d

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

i am trying to run a sample program called device.cpp which came along with chai-3d sdk. i have included the following header files....

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <chai3d.h>
```

the problem is with the header files `math/CVector3d.h` and `math/CMatrix3d.h` which is included in the header file chai3d.h. below is the error i receive during compilation

```
include\math/CVector3d.h(831) : error C3861: 'CHAI_DEBUG_PRINT': identifier not found
include\math/CMatrix3d.h(869) : error C3861: 'CHAI_DEBUG_PRINT': identifier not found
```

when running the program for the first time i got 146 errors and after including `#include <GL/glut.h>` the error were reduced to 2. i am using phantom omni from sensable.  wright now i am working with open-haptics sdk but i also want to try chai-3d,provide me support.

Comment: Have you searched the source files in your project for 'CHAI_DEBUG_PRINT'? Google seems to imply that there should be a #define in at least one of those headers.

Comment: CHAI_DEBUG_PRINT can be found only in the above mentioned header files that too it comes inside a function

  
" inline void print(const unsigned int a_precision=2) const
    {
        string s;
        str(s,a_precision);
        CHAI_DEBUG_PRINT("%s\n",s.c_str());
 }"   
iam new to this technology ,hope u can understand.

Comment: I found this code - is it different to yours? - http://haptix.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/libchai3d/include/chai3d/math/CVector3d.h

Comment: both are same,seems that declaration of #define chai_debug_print is missing in my header files,now those errors are solved.